# 72 Fuji S10s Barrings

Tags: restoration

I have a [72 Fuji S10s](http://www.classicfuji.com/1972_04_S10-S_Page.htm) frame and front fork and all the headset parts to reassemble. However, I'm missing the barrings and I'm not sure of what the correct size barrings I need.

Comment: Bearings? Ball bearings?

Comment: Take the cups (or at least the fork, if the cups are not separate) to a bike shop.  They will be able to provide ball bearings to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "barrings" is the [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "ball + bearing"....

Harris Cyclery says that most (classic, i.e., non-cartridge) [headsets use 5/32" bearings, with 3/16" being rarer](http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/bearings.html). Since bearings are so cheap (US$6-8 for a box of 25-75) you could buy both sizes and see which fits better and use the remainder to overhaul your pedals or hubs, as appropriate. Or take an old bearing if you have one to your local bike shop and have them measure it with their micrometer.

[image]
Harris Cyclery also warns you not to  mix and match old and new bearings -- you should replace them as an entire batch. This is because old bearings will be slightly worn smaller than new ones and using mismatched sizes is a sure way to cause pitted races.

p.s. I hate American customary sizes. The nice thing about cartridge bearings is that most of them are metric.

p.p.s. Beautiful bike. It should restore quite nicely.